# From Array[Any] to Array[Double] in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For this code :

```
var p = result.select("finalFeatures").head.toSeq.toArray
```

The results looks like this :

```
p: Array[Any] = Array([3.0,6.0,-0.7876947819954485,-0.21757635218517163,0.9731844373162398,-0.6641741696340382,-0.6860072219935377,-0.2990737363481845,-0.7075863760365155,0.8188108975549018,-0.8468559840943759,-0.04349947247406488,-0.45236764452589984,1.0333959313820456,0.609756607087835,-0.7106619551471779,-0.7750330808435969,-0.08097610412658443,-0.45338437108038904,-0.2952869863393396,-0.30959772365257004,0.6988768123463287,0.17049117199049213,3.2674649019757385,-0.8333373234944124,1.8462942520757128,-0.49441222531240125,-0.44187299748074166,-0.300810826687287])
```

I need this to be `Array[Double]`
How would i do this ?

Comment: result is dataframe?

Comment: Did you try `.asInstanceOf[Array[Double]]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an `Array` of `Any` to `Double` as follows:

```
 val pAsDouble = p.map(_.toString.toDouble)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following data:

```
val df = Seq(Array("2.3", "2.0", "5")).toDF("finalFeatures")
df.show
```

The output for the previous command will be:

```
+-------------+
|finalFeatures|
+-------------+
|[2.3, 2.0, 5]|
+-------------+
```

df.schema will print `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(finalFeatures,ArrayType(StringType,true),true))` to cast the column into double array you can do:

```
val doubleSeq = df.select($"finalFeatures".cast("array<double>")).head.get(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]
```

And `doubleSeq.foreach(println _)` should have the next output:

```
2.3
2.0
5.0
```

Comment: print schema gives this                                                                                                 root
 |-- finalFeatures: vector (nullable = true)

Comment: gives error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`finalFeatures`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast vector to array<double>;;

Comment: `df.select($"finalFeatures".cast("array<double>")).printSchema` should print `root
 |-- finalFeatures: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)`

Comment: hi @Leothorn could post the schema of result dataframe as well?

Comment: hi @Alexandros . No resultant df . org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`finalFeatures`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast vector to array<double>;;
'Project [unresolvedalias(cast(finalFeatures#9911 as array<double>), None)]

Comment: I mean before applying `.cast("array<double>")`